# How to turn a list of probabilities into binary values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list of probabilities between 0 and 1 stored in a NumPy array. How can I covert these values so that any values >0.5 become 1 and any <0.5 become 0?

What I have is basically:

```
    model = [0.123,0.789,0.456,0.654]
```

and what I want is:

```
    model = [0,1,0,1]
```

This just changes the whole array to 1s and I also tried

I've tried doing it using loops:

```
for i in range(len(model)):
if i<0.5:
    model[i]=0
elif i>0.5:
    model[i]=1
```

This just changes the whole array to 1s and I also tried

```
i = 0
while i <len(model):
    if model[i] < 0.5:
        model[i] = 0
        i + 1
    elif model[i] >0.5:
        model[i] = 1
        i + 1
```

but that didn't work either.

Comment: `list(map(lambda x: int(x>0.5),model))
`

Comment: maybe use `np.round`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example doesn't work because you're not evaluating the values of the `model` array (`model[i]`), you're evaluating the indices of the iterator (`i`).

Your second example doesn't work because `i + 1` doesn't actually change the value of `i`. What you want is: `i += 1`.

There's also a subtle error in your second example, namely that a value of exactly `0.5` will be unchanged, which I assume is not wanted.

You can use Python's [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension) syntax to easily convert the array to the format you want:

```
model = [random.random() for _ in range(5)]
model = [1 if n >= 0.5 else 0 for n in model]
```

Otherwise, here is a traditional loop that does the same thing:

```
for i in range(len(model)):
    if model[i] < 0.5:
        model[i] = 0
    else:
        model[i] = 1
```

Answer (score 6):

Without any additional libraries, you could go with...

```
model = [int(i > .5) for i in model]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) as follows:

`list(np.where(np.array(model) > 0.5, 1, 0 ))`

Also, a simple %timeit comparison of all above/below:

```
In [24]: %timeit np.round(model)                                                                                                                     
12.9 µs ± 69.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [25]: %timeit list(np.where(np.array(model) > 0.5, 1, 0 ))                                                                                        
10.7 µs ± 26.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [26]: %timeit [int(i > .5) for i in model]                                                                                                        
1.28 µs ± 5.02 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [np.vectorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html?highlight=vectorize#numpy.vectorize) function:

```
model = np.array([0.123,0.789,0.456,0.654], dtype='float')
np.vectorize(lambda x: int(x >= 0.5))(model)
```

will return:

`array([0, 1, 0, 1])`

Answer (score 0):

Just use [numpy.round](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.round_.html) function

```py
import numpy as np
model = np.round(model)
```